# Java - pong game graphics not appearing

Tags: java, libgdx, vector-graphics

I can't for the life of me figure out how to create a filled white rectangle on my pong game window. I followed a basic tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MAi2H6lf0A) on using the ShapeRenderer class, but for some reason the tutorial uses the following line -

`ShapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.FilledRectangle)`

However, the IDE i'm using does not understand what FilledRectangle is and throws a cannot resolved symbol error.

I've imported all of the following librarys:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.*;
```

Would anyone know what I could try to get round this?

Comment: Does it resolve all the libraries you are importing?

Comment: Could you provide us with your attempt at it, so we know where to start from?

Comment: Yes, all libraries resolve just fine. Is there a way for me me to upload all my code on this website?

Comment: Either pastebin it, or you can just edit your code straight in. Remember to cut out the unnecessary bits. Cut it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Pastebinned - http://pastebin.com/Cnzgd5F0. This is just one of the classes, will add more in due course

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sS0B6zUs

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9HJaPkhB

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sXghThMF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API changed recently, so rather than using

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
```

use this instead

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
```

and use

```
shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, w, h);
```

to draw a filled rectangle. See [ShapeRenderer.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.java) for more info.

Comment: Follow the Libgdx blog to keep up with API changes before v1.0.  Here's the ShapeRenderer change entry: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2809

Comment: I've now worked this out now - everything compiles correctly, but when i try to run the program I don't see a white square, which should appear within the applet.

Comment: Yes, here you go:  pastebin.com/Cnzgd5F0, pastebin.com/sS0B6zUs, pastebin.com/9HJaPkhB and pastebin.com/sXghThMF

Comment: The problem is that the ball has zero dimensions. Take a look at GameObject's constructor, as it has "bounds" as a local variable, hiding the field that it is trying to set. If you remove the word Rectangle from "Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle()" in GameObject's constructor then you'll see a green square at the bottom left of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.html#FilledRectangle), FilledRectangle is an enum value in the nested enum ShapeType. But [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.html) in the "nighties" this enum value is not present. So there must be some confusion about the library version. Make sure you use the same version in your IDE as in the video (I didn't watch the video).